# Find the perimeter of the convex hull of the self-intersecting 17-gon to the nearest integer.

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be a triangle with AB = 130, BC = 140, CA = 150. Let G, H, I, O, N, K, L be the centroid, orthocenter, incenter, circumenter, nine-point center, the symmedian point, and the de Longchamps point. Let D, E, F be the feet of the altitudes of A, B, C on the sides BC, CA, AB. Let X, Y , Z be the A, B, C excenters and let U, V , W denote the midpoints of IX, IY , IZ (i.e. the midpoints of the arcs of (ABC).) Let R, S, T denote the isogonal conjugates of the midpoints of AD, BE, CF. Let P and Q denote the images of G and H under an inversion around the circumcircle of ABC followed by a dilation at O with factor 1/2 , and denote by M the midpoint of PQ. Then, let J be a point such that JKLM is a parallelogram. Find the perimeter of the convex hull of the self-intersecting 17-gon LETSTRADEBITCOINS to the nearest integer.

Comment: *Which* self-intersecting 17-gon? Please specify the points and their order explicitely. Also let us know what you have tried? Are you using some computer algebra system to tackle this?

Comment: What do you mean? It's self intersecting...
There is no order necessary

Comment: And this problem is not for me - it's for you...

Comment: OK, I missed the fact of the convex hull which makes order irrelevant. So you want the perimeter of the convex hull of some 17 points, but still don't specify which 17 out of 26 points you mention, namely $A,B,C,G,H,I,O,N,K,L,D,E,F,X,Y,Z,U,V,W,R,S,T,P,Q,M,J$. And if the problem is not for you but for me, then I have no interest in spending energy on it. If you know the answer, and I know that I could compute it, I don't have to actually compute it just to know I can. In that case I wonder what's your motivation behind this question.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I'd still be curious as to which 17 points you originally had in mind.

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention the points :P LETSTRADEBITCOINS

Comment: If you edit your question to include that piece of information, I might even remove my downvote. Anyway, updated my answer to take that into account. And I really wonder where this problem came from.

Comment: ok I fixed it :) P.S. you got it right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose coordinates for your original triangle in such a way that all the points along the way are rational:

\begin{align*}
A&= (0, 0) &
A&= (+000.000, +000.000) \\
B&= (130, 0) &
B&= (+130.000, +000.000) \\
C&= (990/13, 1680/13) &
C&\approx (+076.154, +129.231) \\
G&= (2680/39, 560/13) &
G&\approx (+068.718, +043.077) \\
H&= (990/13, 825/26) &
H&\approx (+076.154, +031.731) \\
I&= (70, 40) &
I&= (+070.000, +040.000) \\
O&= (65, 195/4) &
O&= (+065.000, +048.750) \\
N&= (1835/26, 4185/104) &
N&\approx (+070.577, +040.240) \\
K&= (4212/59, 2184/59) &
K&\approx (+071.390, +037.017) \\
L&= (700/13, 855/13) &
L&\approx (+053.846, +065.769) \\
D&= (1440/13, 600/13) &
D&\approx (+110.769, +046.154) \\
E&= (2178/65, 3696/65) &
E&\approx (+033.508, +056.862) \\
F&= (990/13, 0) &
F&\approx (+076.154, +000.000) \\
X&= (210, 120) &
X&= (+210.000, +120.000) \\
Y&= (-80, 140) &
Y&= (-080.000, +140.000) \\
Z&= (60, -105) &
Z&= (+060.000, -105.000) \\
U&= (140, 80) &
U&= (+140.000, +080.000) \\
V&= (-5, 90) &
V&= (-005.000, +090.000) \\
W&= (65, -65/2) &
W&= (+065.000, -032.500) \\
R&= (80, 60) &
R&= (+080.000, +060.000) \\
S&= (12870/211, 10920/211) &
S&\approx (+060.995, +051.754) \\
T&= (132850/2171, 46200/2171) &
T&\approx (+061.193, +021.281) \\
P&= (35165/106, -151905/424) &
P&\approx (+331.745, -358.267) \\
Q&= (16315/106, -36855/424) &
Q&\approx (+153.915, -086.922) \\
M&= (12870/53, -23595/106) &
M&\approx (+242.830, -222.594) \\
J&= (10584458/40651, -20434983/81302) &
J&\approx (+260.374, -251.347)
\end{align*}

Here is an illustration of all 26 points:

[image: Image of all 26 points]

And here a close-up of the crowded central area of the triangle.

[image: Close-up of the central area of the triangle]

For the polygon $LETSTRADEBITCOINS$, most of the above computation is unneccessary. The resulting convex hull will be exactly the triangle $ABC$, and its perimeter can be read from the problem specification, without any need for rounding.

$$ 130+140+150 = 420 $$

This is because these letters do occur in the word, and none of the letters outside the triangle does occur. So all you have to do is verify that $L,E,T,S,R,D,E,I,O,N$ are indeed inside or at the boundary.
$D,E$ are on the boundary by definition.
$I$ is inside by definition.
$O$ is inside since all angles are acute.
$L$ is inside because $O$ is inside.
$R,S,T$ are inside because they are the isogonal conjugate of another point inside.